# phishing link placed on shared hosting web pages

Tags: php, linux, cpanel, shared-hosting, phishing

This morning I received notification from Google (noreply@gooogle.com) that several of my accounts on my shared Linux hosting reseller account had phishing links placed on them. They were all different hosted domains on the same reseller account. The links had something in common, so were probably placed by the same hacker. All suspicious links looked like this:

```
example.com/~cp/request/linkd/index.php?userid=aname%40domain.com
```

I contacted the hosting company about a possible vulnerability on their servers, but I was wondering if these links could have been placed on my accounts due to one of my admin passwords being compromised. I also would like to know where I could find these links and remove them myself. I'm not sure where to track down the `/~cp/request/linkd/` Linux directory. Is this related to a cpanel directory? My search of my file system for index.php did not find any suspicious files or directories.

Also, some sites were running WordPress, but are all up to date and hardened installs, and some sites were basic html5 sites (no WordPress).

Comment: This is off-topic, it is a specific support request topic for your hosting company.

Comment: Completely possible that your cpanel may have been compromised. You will need to do some forensic work. If your cpanel is hosted by your provider, they should have all the logs for this and can help you find out. Since we have no access to this info, no one can answer that question for you.

Comment: The hosting company was contacted and they did disable the user 'cp' account. My question was more to understand how the compromised account was installed on the shared account. Hosting companies constantly fix compromised code without disclosing that there really was an issue or what module or code was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think **cp** user is created on your server and that is the infected USER. I can see mod_userdir is enable on your server and that is the reason they can able to access that infected URL with your domain name (example.com/~cp URL), So please contact your hosting provider and ask them to disable mod_userdir and check that URL again.

Answer (score 0):

This should be addressed by your hosting company. It seems that your hosting server is not configured properly and it allows to access any account using temporary URL using any domain hosted on the server. This is not recommended settings because if one of your accounts is compromised, Google may consider all domains have suspicious code.

You should immediately contact your host to fix this issue. They will have to adjust Apache mod_userdir settings to prevent such issue.